# Super convergent cos(x)

Tags: calculus, bessel-functions

could you find where it come from?
$$\cos (x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left((-1)^n+1\right) e^{\frac{i \pi  n}{2}} (n+1)^2 J_{n+1}(x)}{x}$$ it is seem as bessel series?

Comment: There is a lot of cancellation in the RHS (no contrinute given by odd $n$s): please improve formatting for readability and show your efforts.

Comment: Do you want a derivation, or it this a reference request?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can consider the Fourier series for $\cos(x \cos\theta)$ given by the [Jacobi-Anger expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), differentiate it twice with respect to $\theta$, then evaluate it in $\theta=\pi$. You'll get your identity.

Comment: thanks Jack i do not know the Jacobi-Anger Formula i found this$$e^{i z \cos (\emptyset )}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{2 (n+1)^2 i^n \sec (\emptyset ) J_{n+1}(z \cos (\emptyset ))}{z}$$ i think it is the same

Comment: The Jacobi-Anger formula is the Jacobi-Anger formula (welcome to the tautology club) on line $(66)$ in the linked mathworld page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some if the simplifications
 Jack D'Aurizio mentioned 
in his comment
(this is really a comment,
but the math is too complicated
for me to 
enter it as such):

$\begin{array}\\
\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left((-1)^n+1\right) e^{\frac{i \pi  n}{2}} (n+1)^2 J_{n+1}(x)}{x}
&=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{2 e^{\frac{i \pi 2 n}{2}} (2n+1)^2 J_{2n+1}(x)}{x}
 \quad\text{ (terms 0 for odd n)}\\
&=\frac{2}{x}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }  e^{i \pi  n} (2n+1)^2 J_{2n+1}(x)
\quad (e^{i \pi n} = (-1)^n)\\
&=\frac{2}{x}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }  (-1)^{ n} (2n+1)^2 J_{2n+1}(x)
\text{ }\\
\end{array}
$