# super convergent E^x series

Tags: calculus

I found in a forun the following identity where it come from?
$$e^x=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{I_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(1) \left(2^{n+\frac{1}{2}} x^n \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2},-\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2}-n;\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$
it seem very fast convergence

Comment: Could you provide the link ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Claude it maybe help it must be relationated with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098173/super-convergent-cosx